# Fail when installing debugpy for notebook with pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter

I'm trying to install Jupiter Notebook with pip, seems all packages install sucesfully, I use following query in Windows console:

```
python -m pip install jupyter --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org
```

Also tried:

```
python -m pip install jupyter --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org
```

But still not helped, result always the same:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Downloading notebook-6.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (529 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 529.8/529.8 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Downloading qtconsole-5.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 121.9/121.9 kB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_console-6.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Downloading nbconvert-7.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (290 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 290.4/290.4 kB 9.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipykernel-6.23.3-py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 152.8/152.8 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipywidgets-8.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 138.3/138.3 kB 8.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting comm>=0.1.1 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Downloading comm-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting debugpy>=1.6.5 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Downloading debugpy-1.6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)
     ----------------------------------- ---- 4.3/4.9 MB 863.5 kB/s eta 0:00:01
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    debugpy>=1.6.5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/63/d07f5c023abf3192200344d494118f7a00168d67eec50cc16c9bf20a3333/debugpy-1.6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from ipykernel->jupyter):
        Expected sha256 53f7a456bc50706a0eaabecf2d3ce44c4d5010e46dfc65b6b81a518b42866267
             Got        515b7e9cd4e42a3e9b06991cc1bbb6bf937cf58aef2ec6505424bbca4d8de988
```